# Add class to text (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add class only where text value is: `No rating found`. But it seems that even selecting it doesn't work. I'm trying to add class `("table-danger")` to `td` where text is `No rating found`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".form-inline").submit(doStuff);
});

function doStuff(e){
e.preventDefault();

var input = $("#nanizankaInput").val();
var link = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=";
link = link + input; 

$.ajax({
    url: link,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     $("thead").first().append( "<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.rating.average + "</td>" +"</tr>");
    }


$("thead tr td").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'null')
          $(this).text('No rating found');
     });


if ($("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text() == 'No rating found'){
  $("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").addClass("table-danger")
}

}});
}
```

> **LIVE DEMO**  http://jsbin.com/pimitijigu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can just put the `addClass()` call in the `each()` loop you have which is checking for the `null` value in the `td` cells, like this:

```
$("thead tr td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'null')
    $(this).text('No rating found').addClass('table-danger');
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozsv0zc3/)

> I want to add it to whole row

In this case you could even modify the loop which appends the HTML to perform the logic in a single pass. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var rating = data[i].show.rating.average, ratingClass = '';
  if (!rating) {
    rating = 'No rating found';
    ratingClass = 'table-danger';
  }

  $("thead").first().append('<tr class="' + ratingClass + '"><td>' + data[i].show.id + '</td><td>' + data[i].show.name + '</td><td>' + rating + '</td></tr>');
}
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4h618qkp/)

Comment: This adds class to td:nth-child(3) element only. But I want to add it to whole row ' td '.